# import wikidata json dump to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, wikidata

I downloaded the wikidata json compressed dump which is 7 gb. I extracted it and its 122 gb ! what is the best way to get this data into mongo ?

My real use case is I just want to query this data in python. Is there a better option ?

PS: I'm using my laptop.

Comment: I have been working on a tool to [import a Wikidata dump to CouchDB](https://github.com/maxlath/import-wikidata-dump-to-couchdb), could be useful. I'm using it for dump subsets though; for a full dump, it should probably be [refactored to use the bulk API](https://github.com/maxlath/import-wikidata-dump-to-couchdb/issues/1), I could give it a shot in the coming days if that's of interest.

Answer (score 0):

After obtaining the JSON file, you can simply use the load command to MongoDB:

```
mongoimport --db dbName --collection collectionName --file fileName.json --jsonArray
```